# React - For Loop conditional render - not working and infinite trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically multiple an item in my render based on a variable kind of like this

```
<div>
  <Multiple
    multiple={props.multiple}
    base1={props.base1}
    exp1={props.exp1}
  />
</div>

const Multiple = (props) => {
    let result = "";
    let wtf = "";
    console.log("test"); // gets triggered
    for(let i = 0; i < props.multiple; i++){
        console.log("i: "+i); // gets triggered
        result.concat("{props.base1} +"); // this doesn't work for some reason
        wtf = i; // gets triggered
    }
    console.log("result: "+result); // result is blank
    console.log("wtf:" +wtf);
    return <span>{result}</span>;
}
```

**PROBLEM 1:** Even though I am entering the for-loop, my result is not being changed and i don't understand why.

Also since I cant get it to work yet, I wanted to ask: If i do it this way, where I am concatenating {props.base1} as a string, when i return it in the render, will it show up as "{props.base1}" or will it render as the variable value?

Here is an example as to what it should look like:

```
base1 = abc
multiple = 2

resulting render should look like:
abc + abc +
```

Will concatenating my prop into a string before rendering result it in looking like this instead of the above block?

```
{props.base1} + {props.base1} +
```

**PROBLEM 2: EDIT** ALSO, for some reason everything in the `<Multiple>` component is infinitely triggering, which I also do not understand why it is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using concat, which doesn't update the original string, it creates a new string instead. What you could do is either

```js
let result = '';
for(let i = 0; i < props.multiple; i++) {
  console.log("i: "+i); // gets triggered
  result += `${props.base1} `; 
  wtf = i; // gets triggered
}
console.log(result);
```

2. As far as the infinite loop problem goes, what actually is `props.muitlple`? Is it an array or a string? If so, you should change your loop to

`for(let i = 0; i < props.multiple.length; i++)`

**Edit:** if props.multiple is a number, `i < props.multiple` should work, you should log the value in your component and check once.

Comment: as shown in the example at the bottom of my post, multiple is a number

Comment: I do log the value, the loop runs and i console.log(i), however everything inside <Multiple> is being infinitely looped, so I am constantly console.logging the "test" and the for-loop

Comment: Where did you log the value of props.multiple? Was it above the loop? Can you just comment the loop and add `console.log('mutliple', props.multiple)` and see what it prints.

Comment: Refer to the whole `const Multiple = (props) => {...` block.


I worded it wrong initially,more accurately, every console.log in the <Multiple> component is infinitely printing in my console

Answer (score 0):

The result string is not being properly appended to

```
const Multiple = (props) => {
    let result = "";
    let wtf = "";
    
    for(let i = 0; i < props.multiple; i++){
        result += props.base1.toString() + "+"
   
    }
    console.log("result: "+result); 
    return <span>{result}</span>;
}
```

For the infinite loop I would check it's values before entering the loop to make sure your bounds are properly set.

```
// add this line before for loop
console.log(props.multiple)
```

Comment: I worded it wrong initially, its not just the for-loop that is infinitely looping. All my console.log statements in the <Multiple> component is being infinitely logged on my console.

Comment: @Jeffrey To solve your problem more information on the parent component would be helpful. Hard to tell just off the information provided.

Comment: TBH agreed, I generally dislike using stackOverflow because its too hard to explain a problem without actually being able to SHOW the problem

Comment: To explain your problem it would be helpful to provide information on your parent component. However, it might be better to make a different post.

Answer (score -1):

a. change to `result.concat('${props.base1} + ');` (backtics!!)

b. i think that maybe there is a problem with the props you pass to `<Multiple ... >`. check again their value, maybe log their value.

Comment: right..result = result.concat('${props.base1} + ');